# CRM 2011: Change Value OnCreate on Form with JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to change the value of a field with javascript on the OnSave Event of a Form in CRM 2011. This should only occur if the entity is created.

This means I check the FormMode for OnCreate and then try to change a field value with:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("field").setValue("asd"); 
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

or

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("field").setValue("asd");
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

neither of them is working. How do I save/change the value OnCreate with JavaScript in a CRM 2011 Form?

---

Code:

```
function doSomeThingOnSave(ExecutionObj) {
    var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
    if (formType != 1) return;
    var odataSelect = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    odataSelect += "/blablabla";

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: odataSelect,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        if (data.d.results != null && data.d.results[0] != null) {
            var value= data.d.results[0].asdsda;

        var field = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('sad');
        if (field != null) {
            field.setSubmitMode("always");
            field.setValue(field.getValue() +value);
            }
}

    },
    error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (errorThrown != "Forbidden")
            alert('OData Select Failed: ' + odataSelect);
    }
});
```

}

seems that my call was asynchronous. The correct code would be making the call synchron with `async:false`

Comment: Post your entire `OnSave` function.

Answer (score 0):

I always use your second example to set the value, but since you're already in the `OnSave` event of the form, you shouldn't have to explicitly call `entity.save()`.